# Get Toolbar in dynamically added Text view in Linear Layout

Tags: android, mysql, android-xml

In my app I am fetching the order details from the mysql db and based on the number of rows in db I am dynamically adding the `TextView` in my `LinearLayout` in the app(if there are 6 rows then 6 text views will be displayed in the app)
In doing the toolbar is disabled from the `Activity` and due to this i am NOT able to go back to my parent activity
I am NOT sure but I think using `setLayoutParams` is the culprit here.

Please help!

```
public class OrderHistory extends AppCompatActivity  {

private EditText editTextId;
private Button buttonGet;
private TextView textViewResult;

private ProgressDialog loading;
private ScrollView scrollView;
private LinearLayout linearLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_history);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    getData(); //get data from the db

}

private void getData() {
   //getting data from db
}

private void showJSON(String response){

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Constants.JSON_ARRAY);
        this.scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollableContents);
        this.linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
        this.linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        TextView[] t1 = new TextView[result.length()];
        TextView[] t2 = new TextView[result.length()];
        TextView[] t3 = new TextView[result.length()];
        TextView[] t4 = new TextView[result.length()];
        TextView[] t5 = new TextView[result.length()];
        ImageView[] img = new ImageView[result.length()];


        if(result.length()!=0) {

            for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(i);


                int orderTotal = Integer.parseInt(collegeData.getString(Constants.KEY_AMOUNT).split("\\ ")[0]) - 49;
                int total = orderTotal + 49;

                switch (collegeData.getString(Constants.KEY_CCAvenueOrderStatus)) {
                    case "Success":
                        t1[i] = new TextView(this);
                        t1[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    //when this is execute the TOOLBAR disappears #i guess
                        String success = (i + 1) + "." + "Payment of ₹" + collegeData.getString(Constants.KEY_AMOUNT) + " was received by Horoscope Daily !";
                        t1[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                        t1[i].setTextSize(17);
                        t1[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("<h4>" + success + "</h4>" + "Your transaction was successfull<br> Order Number<br>" + "<b>" + collegeData.getString(Constants.KEY_ORDERID) + "</b>" + "<br>" + collegeData.getString(Constants.KEY_DATE) + "<br>"));
                        this.linearLayout.addView(t1[i]);

                        break;


                    case "Failure":
                        t1[i] = new TextView(this);
                        t1[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        String failure = (i + 1) + "." + "Payment of ₹" + collegeData.getString(Constants.KEY_AMOUNT) + " failed !";
                        t1[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                        t1[i].setTextSize(17);
                        t1[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("<h4>" + failure + "</h4>" + "Your payment has been declined by your bank.Please contact your bank for any queries.If money has been deducted from your account,your bank will inform us within 48 hrs and we will refund the same<br><br> Order Number<br>" + "<b>" + collegeData.getString(Constants.KEY_ORDERID) + "</b>" + "<br>" + collegeData.getString(Constants.KEY_DATE) + "<br>"));
                        this.linearLayout.addView(t1[i]);

                        break;


                    case "Aborted":
                        t1[i] = new TextView(this);
                        t1[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        String aborted = (i + 1) + "." + "Payment of ₹" + collegeData.getString(Constants.KEY_AMOUNT) + " failed !";
                        t1[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                        t1[i].setTextSize(17);
                        t1[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("<h4>" + aborted + "</h4>" + "Your payment has been declined by your bank as the OTP(one time password) entered is incorrect.Please try again with the correct OTP or contact your bank for any queries.<br><br> Order Number<br>" + "<b>" + collegeData.getString(Constants.KEY_ORDERID) + "</b>" + "<br>" + collegeData.getString(Constants.KEY_DATE) + "<br>"));
                        this.linearLayout.addView(t1[i]);
                        break;


                    default:
                }


                t3[i] = new TextView(this);
                t3[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                t3[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                t3[i].setTextSize(17);
                t3[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("<h4>You have below Items in your order</h4> <br>" + collegeData.getString(Constants.KEY_ITEM) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + "₹ " + orderTotal + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + collegeData.getString(Constants.KEY_RATTI) + " Ratti" + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + collegeData.getString(Constants.KEY_QUANTITY) + " Quantity" + "<br>"));
                this.linearLayout.addView(t3[i]);

                switch (collegeData.getString(Constants.KEY_ITEM)) {
                    case "Coral":
                        String uri = "@drawable/ic_coral_moonga";  // where myresource (without the extension) is the file
                        int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());
                        img[i] = new ImageView(this);
                        img[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        img[i].getLayoutParams().height = 200;
                        img[i].getLayoutParams().width = 200;
                        Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
                        img[i].setImageDrawable(res);
                        this.linearLayout.addView(img[i]);


                        break;
                    case "Opal":

                        img[i] = new ImageView(this);
                        img[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        img[i].getLayoutParams().height = 200;
                        img[i].getLayoutParams().width = 200;
                        img[i].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/ic_opal", null, getPackageName())));
                        this.linearLayout.addView(img[i]);

                        break;
                    case "Emerald":
                        img[i] = new ImageView(this);
                        img[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        img[i].getLayoutParams().height = 200;
                        img[i].getLayoutParams().width = 200;
                        img[i].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/ic_emerald_panna", null, getPackageName())));
                        this.linearLayout.addView(img[i]);


                        break;
                    case "Pearl":
                        img[i] = new ImageView(this);
                        img[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        img[i].getLayoutParams().height = 200;
                        img[i].getLayoutParams().width = 200;
                        img[i].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/ic_pearl_moti", null, getPackageName())));
                        this.linearLayout.addView(img[i]);

                        break;

                    case "Ruby":
                        img[i] = new ImageView(this);
                        img[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        img[i].getLayoutParams().height = 200;
                        img[i].getLayoutParams().width = 200;
                        img[i].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/ic_ruby_manikya", null, getPackageName())));
                        this.linearLayout.addView(img[i]);

                        break;


                    case "Yellow Sapphire":
                        img[i] = new ImageView(this);
                        img[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        img[i].getLayoutParams().height = 200;
                        img[i].getLayoutParams().width = 200;
                        img[i].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/ic_yellow_sapphire_pikhraj", null, getPackageName())));
                        this.linearLayout.addView(img[i]);

                        break;

                    case "Blue Sapphire":
                        img[i] = new ImageView(this);
                        img[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        img[i].getLayoutParams().height = 200;
                        img[i].getLayoutParams().width = 200;
                        img[i].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/ic_blue_sapphire", null, getPackageName())));
                        this.linearLayout.addView(img[i]);

                        break;


                    default:

                        break;
                }


                t4[i] = new TextView(this);
                t4[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                t4[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                t4[i].setTextSize(17);
                t4[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("<br><h4>Payment Details</h4> CC Tracking ID <br>" + collegeData.getString(Constants.KEY_CCAvenueTacking_id) + "<br>"));
                this.linearLayout.addView(t4[i]);

                t5[i] = new TextView(this);
                t5[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                t5[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("<h4>Summary</h4> <br>" + "Order Total" + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + "₹ " + orderTotal + "<br>" + "Shipping" + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + "₹ 49" + "<br>" + "Total" + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + "₹ " + total + "<br>"));
                t5[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                t5[i].setTextSize(17);
                this.linearLayout.addView(t5[i]);


                View v = new View(this);
                v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        5
                ));
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#B3B3B3"));

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams margin = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                margin.setMargins(0, 50, 0, 50);
                v.setLayoutParams(margin);


                this.linearLayout.addView(v);


            }
            if (this.scrollView.getParent() != null)
                ((ViewGroup) this.scrollView.getParent()).removeView(this.scrollView);
            setContentView(this.scrollView);

        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No Order History\n"+"Our database indicate that you don't have any orders yet !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // hide the progress dialog
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  //  textViewResult.setText("Name:\t"+name+"\nAddress:\t" +address+ "\nVice Chancellor:\t"+ vc);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you able to go back to previous screen if you had not called your `getData()` ?

Comment: getData() is fine .Yes i am able to go back i.e toolbar is visible till getData()

Comment: Why are you using `LinearLayout` directly instead of `ListView` or `RecyclerView`?. And looks like you are blocking UI thread on `getData()`. Move loading data from DB to `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I dont know how to use RecyclerView or ListView

Answer (score 1):

Remove this code it is not needed:

```
if (this.scrollView.getParent() != null)
   ((ViewGroup)this.scrollView.getParent()).removeView(this.scrollView);    

setContentView(this.scrollView);
```

Move reading from DB to `AsyncTask` - because you are blocking UI thread on call to `getData()` and `Application` freezes durring loading.

Also you need think about using proper container like [`ListView`](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) or [`RecycleView`](https://www.raywenderlich.com/126528/android-recyclerview-tutorial)

Comment: I dont know how to use RecyclerView or ListView